# Find 'contributor' users associated with posts in a WordPress Database

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to pull information out of a WordPress database, and add it to my own (structured differently & not for running a WordPress site on)

On this WordPress website, users are assigned the 'contributor' group/permissions on a specific post, so they can edit only that post.

On my database, I have copied across all of the posts and all of the users from the WordPress database.

Now somewhere in the WordPress database there should be something linking the user and post together via an 'ID' to give them contributor status for that post.

I have managed to find the following:

`wp_usermeta` table:

```
user_id: 8
meta_key: wp_capabilities
meta_value: a:1:{s:11:"contributor";b:1;}
```

So here we can see we have our user and capabilities, with a `user_id` of '8' and `meta_value` of 'contributor'... but I can't find anything to link the user with the posts they have been assigned to. Somewhere I am expecting to find a user id and post id in the same row, linking the two so I know which user relates to which post, but I've had no luck, even after much research.

So if anyone is experienced with WP databases, please help :(

Comment: Did you mean `post_author` in `wp_posts` table ??

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thanks pgk... So what do I do now? Delete this post out of shame? lol

Comment: You are welcome :) I can post this as answer and you can accept and mark the question as answered or of course you can delete it :). Your decision.

Comment: Could be useful for other people who stumble across it so will leave it here... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find user posts using `post_author` filed in `wp_posts` table.